# hexic polynomial question

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials

I am faced with a polynomial of the form
$$
ax^6+bx^3+cx+d=0,
$$
where the coefficients are complex. I want to be able to say something about the roots of this polynomial (including finding them!). Is this feasible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The general sextic polynomial cannot be solved in radicals, and I don't see any reason why this family should be special in this way. So I suspect the vast majority of these polynomials do not have a closed-form solution in the sense of being able to write them down with radicals and arithmetic operations. Of course there are plenty of numerical methods for approximating the roots as closely as you want. There are also ways to say some qualitiative things about the roots: for example, all the roots are complex numbers of modulus at most $\max\{1,\sqrt[3]{(|b|+|c|+|d|)/|a|}\}$, and they're unlikely to be all real by Descartes's rule of signs.